# How to shrink root filesystem without booting a livecd

Tags: centos, lvm

I find myself needing to rearrange a system's partitions to move data previously under the root filesystem into dedicated mount points. The volumes are all in LVM, so this is relatively easy: create new volumes, move data into them, shrink the root filesystem, then mount the new volumes at the appropriate points.

The issue is step 3, shrinking the root filesystem. The filesystems involved are ext4, so online resizing is supported; however, while mounted, the filesystems can only be grown. To shrink the partition requires unmounting it, which of course is not possible for the root partition in normal operation.

Answers around the Web seem to revolve around booting a LiveCD or other rescue media, doing the shrink operation, then booting back into the installed system. However, the system in question is remote, and I have access only via SSH. I can reboot, but booting a rescue disc and doing operations from the console is not possible.

How can I unmount the root filesystem while maintaining remote shell access?

Comment: Any opportunity to temporarily mount the root filesystem on a different server ?  e.g. spin up another VM and present this disk volume to it ?

Comment: The server is physical, so no.

Comment: Copy root to tmpfs and `pivot_root` onto there.  An example here http://dreamlayers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/running-linux-from-ram.html - it tricky but if you have a test box to try it on, worth considering.

Comment: Hmm. Using that method, how will the sshd survive? Or could I start a new sshd from the tmpfs and connect to that?

Comment: Another example here, where remote access via ssh is considered http://www.ivarch.com/blogs/oss/2007/01/resize-a-live-root-fs-a-howto.shtml

Comment: That looks very close to what I need to do. Thanks.

Comment: If the root LVM is small enough you can clone it to another LVM and create boot eatery (temp new default) in grub to use it, and then boot from it (making it your "live system")

Comment: I ended up solving the problem using information derived from the link @steve provided. However, it also required significant trial-and-error, and I'd like the final answer to include those results. Would it be proper to post my own answer here?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal tom, will be useful for all to know the steps.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

In solving this issue, the information provided at https://www.ivarch.com/blogs/oss/2007/01/resize-a-live-root-fs-a-howto.shtml was pivotal. However, that guide is for a very old version of RHEL, and various information was obsolete.

The instructions below are crafted to work with CentOS 7, but they should be easily enough transferable to any distro that runs systemd. All commands are run as root.

1. Ensure the system is in a stable state

   Make sure no one else is using it and nothing else important is going on. It's probably a good idea to stop service-providing units like httpd or ftpd, just to ensure external connections don't disrupt things in the middle.

   ```
    systemctl stop httpd
    systemctl stop nfs-server
    # and so on....
   ```

   Make sure you have `lsof` installed (`lsof -v`). And that `fuser` (`fuser -V`) in installed too (Debian/Ubuntu package: `psmisc`).
2. Unmount all unused filesystems

   ```
    umount -a
   ```

   This will print a number of 'Target is busy' warnings, for the root volume itself and for various temporary/system FSs. These can be ignored for the moment. What's important is that no on-disk filesystems remain mounted, except the root filesystem itself. Verify this:

   ```
    # mount alone provides the info, but column makes it possible to read
    mount | column -t
   ```

   If you see any on-disk filesystems still mounted, then something is still running that shouldn't be. Check what it is using `fuser`:

   ```
    # if necessary:
    yum install psmisc
    # then:
    fuser -vm <mountpoint>
    systemctl stop <whatever>
    umount -a
    # repeat as required...
   ```
3. Make the temporary root
   Note: if /tmp is a directory on /, we will not be able to unmount / later in this procedure if we use /tmp/tmproot. Thus it may be necessary to use an alternative mountpoint such as /tmproot instead.

   ```
    mkdir /tmp/tmproot
    mount -t tmpfs none /tmp/tmproot
    mkdir /tmp/tmproot/{proc,sys,dev,run,usr,var,tmp,oldroot}
    cp -ax /{bin,etc,mnt,sbin,lib,lib64} /tmp/tmproot/
    cp -ax /usr/{bin,sbin,lib,lib64} /tmp/tmproot/usr/
    cp -ax /var/{account,empty,lib,local,lock,nis,opt,preserve,run,spool,tmp,yp} /tmp/tmproot/var/
   ```

   This creates a very minimal root system, which breaks (among other things) manpage viewing (no `/usr/share`), user-level customizations (no `/root` or `/home`) and so forth. This is intentional, as it constitutes encouragement not to stay in such a jury-rigged root system any longer than necessary.

   At this point you should also ensure that all the necessary software is installed, as it will also assuredly break the package manager. Glance through all the steps, and make sure you have the necessary executables.
4. Pivot into the root

   ```
    mount --make-rprivate / # necessary for pivot_root to work
    pivot_root /tmp/tmproot /tmp/tmproot/oldroot
    for i in dev proc sys run; do mount --move /oldroot/$i /$i; done
   ```

   systemd causes mounts to allow subtree sharing by default (as with `mount --make-shared`), and this causes `pivot_root` to fail. Hence, we turn this off globally with `mount --make-rprivate /`. System and temporary filesystems are moved wholesale into the new root. This is necessary to make it work at all; the sockets for communication with systemd, among other things, live in `/run`, and so there's no way to make running processes close it.
5. Ensure remote access survived the changeover

   ```
    systemctl restart sshd
    systemctl status sshd
   ```

   After restarting sshd, ensure that you can get in, by opening another terminal and connecting to the machine again via ssh. If you can't, fix the problem before moving on.

   Once you've verified you can connect in again, exit the shell you're currently using and reconnect. This allows the remaining forked `sshd` to exit and ensures the new one isn't holding `/oldroot`.
6. Close everything still using the old root

   ```
    fuser -vm /oldroot
   ```

   This will print a list of processes still holding onto the old root directory. On my system, it looked like this:

   ```
                 USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
    /oldroot:    root     kernel mount /oldroot
                 root          1 ...e. systemd
                 root        549 ...e. systemd-journal
                 root        563 ...e. lvmetad
                 root        581 f..e. systemd-udevd
                 root        700 F..e. auditd
                 root        723 ...e. NetworkManager
                 root        727 ...e. irqbalance
                 root        730 F..e. tuned
                 root        736 ...e. smartd
                 root        737 F..e. rsyslogd
                 root        741 ...e. abrtd
                 chrony      742 ...e. chronyd
                 root        743 ...e. abrt-watch-log
                 libstoragemgmt    745 ...e. lsmd
                 root        746 ...e. systemd-logind
                 dbus        747 ...e. dbus-daemon
                 root        753 ..ce. atd
                 root        754 ...e. crond
                 root        770 ...e. agetty
                 polkitd     782 ...e. polkitd
                 root       1682 F.ce. master
                 postfix    1714 ..ce. qmgr
                 postfix   12658 ..ce. pickup
   ```

   You need to deal with each one of these processes before you can unmount `/oldroot`. The brute-force approach is simply `kill $PID` for each, but this can break things. To do it more softly:

   ```
    systemctl | grep running
   ```

   This creates a list of running services. You should be able to correlate this with the list of processes holding `/oldroot`, then issue `systemctl restart` for each of them. Some services will refuse to come up in the temporary root and enter a failed state; these don't really matter for the moment.

   If the root drive you want to resize is an LVM drive, you may also need to restart some other running services, even if they do not show up in the list created by `fuser -vm /oldroot`. You might be unable to to resize an LVM drive under Step 7 because of this Error:

   ```
    fsadm: Cannot proceed with mounted filesystem "/oldroot"
   ```

   You can try `systemctl restart systemd-udevd` and if that fails, you can find the leftover mounts with `grep system /proc/*/mounts | column -t`

   Look for processes that say `mounts:none` and try restarting these:

   ```
    PATH                      BIN                        FSTYPE
    /proc/16395/mounts:tmpfs  /run/systemd/timesync      tmpfs
    /proc/16395/mounts:none   /var/lib/systemd/timesync  tmpfs
    /proc/18485/mounts:tmpfs  /run/systemd/inhibit       tmpfs
    /proc/18485/mounts:tmpfs  /run/systemd/seats         tmpfs
    /proc/18485/mounts:tmpfs  /run/systemd/sessions      tmpfs
    /proc/18485/mounts:tmpfs  /run/systemd/shutdown      tmpfs
    /proc/18485/mounts:tmpfs  /run/systemd/users         tmpfs
    /proc/18485/mounts:none   /var/lib/systemd/linger    tmpfs
   ```

   Some processes can't be dealt with via simple `systemctl restart`. For me these included `auditd` (which doesn't like to be killed via `systemctl`, and so just wanted a `kill -15`). These can be dealt with individually.

   The last process you'll find, usually, is `systemd` itself. For this, run `systemctl daemon-reexec`.

   Once you're done, the table should look like this:

   ```
                 USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
    /oldroot:    root     kernel mount /oldroot
   ```
7. Unmount the old root

   ```
    umount /oldroot
   ```

   At this point, you can carry out whatever manipulations you require. The original question needed a simple `resize2fs` invocation, but you can do whatever you want here; one other use case is transferring the root filesystem from a simple partition to LVM/RAID/whatever.
8. Pivot the root back

   ```
    mount <blockdev> /oldroot
    mount --make-rprivate / # again
    pivot_root /oldroot /oldroot/tmp/tmproot
    for i in dev proc sys run; do mount --move /tmp/tmproot/$i /$i; done
   ```

   This is a straightforward reversal of step 4.
9. Dispose of the temporary root

   Repeat steps 5 and 6, except using `/tmp/tmproot` in place of `/oldroot`. Then:

   ```
    umount /tmp/tmproot
    rmdir /tmp/tmproot
   ```

   Since it's a tmpfs, at this point the temporary root dissolves into the ether, never to be seen again.
10. Put things back in their places

    Mount filesystems again:

    ```
    mount -a
    ```

    At this point, you should also update `/etc/fstab` and `grub.cfg` in accordance with any adjustments you made during step 7.

    Restart any failed services:

    ```
    systemctl | grep failed
    systemctl restart <whatever>
    ```

    Allow shared subtrees again:

    ```
    mount --make-rshared /
    ```

    Start the stopped service units - you can use this single command:

    ```
    systemctl isolate default.target
    ```

And you're done.

Many thanks to Andrew Wood, who worked out this evolution on RHEL4, and steve, who provided me the link to the former.

Comment: Excellent summary, great to have the systemd aspects all covered.

Comment: Awesome answer. Nearly magical, and very clear and straightforward. Used it with debian VPS without any issues (just had to ``umount /oldroot/boot`` of course, on stage 6). I'm linking your answer to other SE questions that had no reponse or negative answer.

Comment: Everytime I do this, when I get to step 7, I am able to unmount /oldroot, but then resize2fs gives me "Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda3" If I remount and fuser, all I see is: `/oldroot: root kernel mount /oldroot`. Any guesses? If I rollback, I am also unable to remove /tmp/tmproot, but lsof reports empty.

Comment: And resolved, the issue was as @vaab indicated; you must `umount /oldroot/boot` before you `umount /oldroot`

Comment: Hmm. I would expect any `/boot` partition to be unmounted after stage 2, but I suppose it's possible something might be holding it open at that point.

Comment: Step 1 is a show stopper for me. What's the point of online shrinking if I have to shutdown all the network services?

Comment: The point is to unmount and manipulate the root filesystem without needing a physical console. As far as I know, there's no way to keep open a service that reads from a partition while unmounting that partition. If your service doesn't touch the root FS, it's possible you could keep it open using `mount --move` into the tmpfs, but that is unsupported.

Comment: This is great, thanks @TomHunt.
If I can add just one thing, in the case where you can not login as root directly and you need to use sudo, please add /usr/libexec and /home to the list of directories to copy on step 3.

Comment: What's needed in `/home`? Not sure that's a good idea in the general case; `/home` can be large. (You could `mount --move` it, if it's on a separate mountpoint.)

Comment: I'm using an upstart-based distro instead of systemd, and keep getting stuck at the end of step 6. If I just kill the process directly, my machine crashes. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: You need to use the OS facilities to restart the init daemon. I've never used upstart, but https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/QuantalUpstartStatefulReexec suggests that `telinit u` might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @TomHunt, `telinit u` kept crashing my box with a message of `kernel panic not syncing attempted to kill init`. I decided to try a different approach: I modified the ramdisk in /boot and resized my file system before it was mounted during startup. I appreciate your checking in and your initial answer.

Comment: I love how people are able to figure out a way to do stuff like this

Comment: An additional wrinkle I ran into: /tmp is a ramdisk on my system, so I ended up with a ramdisk mounted at `/oldroot/tmp`, which prevented me from unmounting `/oldroot`, but doesn't show up in `fuser` or `lsof` output. Took a bit of staring at systemd to work that one out...

Comment: I needed to exclude `/var/lib/docker` from being copied to the tmpfs. I also needed `/var/run` in order to restart `sshd`. I was able to do this with `ln -s /run /var/run`

Comment: Use `umount -r /oldroot`, to unmount recursively.

Comment: For some reason `systemctl daemon-reexec` hangs forever on my VM. 8G RAM should be enough, right? I can't guess this reason

Comment: On my ubuntu server 16.04, unmounting /oldroot always fails although `fuser` and `lsof` outputs are empty.

Comment: I copied `/usr/libexec` to the `tmproot` to get sudo working. `dbus` and `auditd` were `kill -15`ed last, after `systemctl daemon-reexec`, because killing `dbus` causes `systemctl` to timemout. I then rebooted with `systemctl --force --force reboot`.

Comment: I have the same need as the original poster except my system is not running LVM (yet) and I want to shrink the / partition to make some room to set up LVM. Unfortunately, whenever I try to those instructions, I can umount /oldroot but resize2fs fails with `resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda3`… Note that I triple-checked that nothing was mounted below /oldroot. I am using Debian Buster. Any hint?

Comment: If you have more complex mounts than the default install, you might want to check output of `findmnt` or `lsblk` or `lsblk -s`, too. For example, mdraid devices, LVM or bind mounts may require extra steps.

Comment: Note that you need enough RAM or swap on some non-root device to allow keeping all the stuff in tmpfs while configuring the root partition. Also understand that if you lose power on the server while the reconfiguration is going, you need real console access to recover.

Comment: I also needed to turn off the swap because `/oldroot/var/swap` was still mounted.  I used a `swapoff -a`

Comment: Great thanks @TomHunt; spent 3 days trying all approaches and approx. tried this method over 20-30 times and after a lot of bac kand forth, found that `/oldroot/var/run` is busy while `fuser -vm /oldroot` didn't show it (detected this by runing `umount /oldroot/**/*` and checking errors)

Comment: the problem went worse when found out that `systemctl daemon-reexec` does not remove `systemd` process on `/oldroot/var/run`, so final attempt I did was to `rm -rf /oldroot/var/run/systemd` and `kill 1`, then magically after unmounting `/oldroot` the partition was no more busy and could `shrink` it. The strange thing was the system crashed after few minutes so you'll have to be fast doing the changes to disk. And also had to run `partprobe /dev/sda` to apply changes because without it changes were gone after reboot

Comment: (not sure if the systemd removal is a good idea nor if it's really mandatory, these just worked and it didn't seem to work when I didn't remove, so I assume that was required)

Comment: This is great ! But lacks instructions to properly copy the ssh authorized keys for the user. And should say to install fuser.

Comment: Not working for me. I am able to unmount /oldroot without any errors and "df" shows only tmpfs mounted. But if I try to do anything with the unmounted /dev/XXX it still says it's being used. "e2fsck" reports "/dev/XXX is in use".

Answer (score 15):

If you are sure what you are doing - thus not experimenting, you may hook into initrd which is the non-interactive and fast way.

On a Debian based system here is how.

See the code: https://github.com/szepeviktor/debian-server-tools/blob/master/debian-setup/debian-resizefs.sh

There is another example: https://github.com/szepeviktor/debian-server-tools/blob/master/debian-setup/debian-convert-ext3-ext4.sh

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: This is a sound approach. I like mine for letting me do the necessary manipulations interactively; however, this one is probably faster. It might be good to edit some more details into the answer itself, or to consider other platforms (it seems this general approach would still work with dracut or mkinitcpio or any other vaguely modern initramfs generator).

Comment: Sorry @stephen-rauch I was just pointing out the idea not the execution.

Answer (score -3):

What I did on a DigitalOcean VPS (having 25G /dev/vda1 mounted as root) :

1. using fdisk, delete the first (25G) partition
2. create a 20G partition (the first sector must be same as the original one)
3. create a new partition (obviously with size 5G), it will be /dev/vda2
4. write partition table and exit fdisk.
5. create an ext4 filesystem on /dev/vda2
6. note the UUIDs of both partitions (ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid)
7. replace /dev/vda1 UUID to /dev/vda2 UUID in /boot/grub/grub.cfg and /etc/fstab
8. mount /dev/vda2 to /mnt
9. copy everything (except dev,proc,run,sys,mnt) from / to /mnt
10. run `update-grub`
11. `reboot` and pray

The above worked well when I was told the resize2fs is not supported.

Comment: This will only work if all the data on /dev/vda1 is within the first 20G of the device. Thus, it requires that the first partition be less than 80% full, and _never have been_ more than 80% full. Also, there's no way to verify this condition via userspace tools, so you're rolling the dice with data loss when you overwrite the last 5G of the partition.

Comment: -1 As Tom Hunt wrote, this is not a safe trick to attempt. Also, if I read the description correctly, you're creating new partition in same drive area that's already mounted as the root. When you write any file to it the changes are you corrupt the currently mounted root filesystem and you may corrupt a file that is going to be copied next. The only way to make this work is if you have as much disk cache as you have file data and *all* files are fully in the cache. Even in that case you'd be much better with using `tmpfs` as temporary root as described in answer by Tom Hunt.

Comment: For a case like this, I'd recommend purchasing extra disk from VPS provider, copying root on that and configuring grub and fstab to use that as root and rebooting. Then recreating the smaller root that you want, copying files again and reconfiguring grup and fstab to use the new smaller root area. The you can delete the temporary partition on "loaned" virtual disk and return it to the VPS provider. This allows you to continue in case kernel crashes while you're reconfiguring the new root.