# Project Quota on a live root EXT4 filesystem without live-cd

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, ramdisk, lxd

How do I accomplish setting up project quota for my live root folder being ext4 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Documentation specific to project quota on the ext4 filesystem is basically non-existent and I tried this:

1. Installed Quota with `apt install quota -y`
2. Put `prjquota` into `/etc/fstab` for the root / and rebooted, filesystem got booted as read-only, no project quota (from [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Quota/) only with prjquota instead of the user and group quotas)
3. Also `` find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -type f -name '*quota_v*.ko*' `` was run and both kernel modules `/lib/modules/4.15.0-96-generic/kernel/fs/quota/quota_v2.ko` and `/lib/modules/4.15.0-96-generic/kernel/fs/quota/quota_v1.ko` were found (from [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-filesystem-quotas-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial)
4. Put `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootflags=prjquota"` into `/etc/default/grub`, ran `update-grub` and rebooted, machine does not come up anymore.
5. Putting `rootflags=quota` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... rootflags=quota"` running `update-grub` and restarting did show `quota` and `usrquota` being enabled on root, but it does not work with `prjquota` or `pquota` or `project` being set as an rootflag

I need this for the DIR storage backend of [LXD](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/introduction/) to be able to limit container storage size.
What else can I try?

Comment: _tried several things already_ What, specifically, was tried, and what was the response for each? Web links to the sources of what you tried would also be welcome.

Comment: I put the 2 major steps I took and the responses into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was told running `tune2fs -O project -Q prjquota /dev/sdaX` is absolutely essential to enable Project Quota on a device. So I searched for a solution that does not require switching off or using a live-cd as this requires too much time and does not always work well in my experience with my VPS provider. And I also hoped that I can turn the steps into a script, which did not work out so far.

Thanks to another question I was able to put together a solution that worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. You do need ca. 4GB of RAM to do this (and of course a kernel after version 4.4).

Sources:

- [How to shrink root filesystem without booting a livecd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226872/how-to-shrink-root-filesystem-without-booting-a-livecd/227318#227318)
- http://www.ivarch.com/blogs/oss/2007/01/resize-a-live-root-fs-a-howto.shtml

**1. Make a RAMdisk filesystem**

```
mkdir /tmp/tmproot
mount none /tmp/tmproot -t tmpfs -o rw
mkdir /tmp/tmproot/{proc,oldroot,sys}
cp -a /dev /tmp/tmproot/dev
cp -ax /{bin,etc,opt,run,usr,home,mnt,sbin,lib,lib64,var,root,srv} /tmp/tmproot/
```

**2. Switch root to the new RAMdisk filesystem**

```
cd /tmp/tmproot
unshare -m
pivot_root /tmp/tmproot/ /tmp/tmproot/oldroot
mount none /proc -t proc
mount none /sys -t sysfs
mount none /dev/pts -t devpts
```

**3. Restart SSH on another port than 22 and reconnect with another session**

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

- Change the port to 2211
- Restart SSH with `/usr/sbin/sshd -D &`
- Connect again from 2211

**4. Kill processes using /oldroot or /dev/sdaX**

```
fuser -km /oldroot
fuser -km /dev/sdaX
```

**5. Unmount /dev/sdaX and apply the project quota feature**

```
umount -l /dev/sdaX
tune2fs -O project -Q prjquota /dev/sdaX
```

**6. Mount with Project Quota**

```
mount /dev/sda2 -o prjquota /oldroot
```

**7. Putting things back**

```
pivot_root /oldroot /oldroot/tmp/tmproot
umount /tmp/tmproot/proc
mount none /proc -t proc
cp -ax /tmp/tmproot/dev/* /dev/
mount /dev/sda1 /boot  ### This might be different for you
reboot -f
```

**8. Turn quota on after reboot**

```
apt install quota -y
quotaon -Pv -F vfsv1 /
```

**9. Check if quota is on on root**

```
repquota -Ps /
```

**10. Make it persistent**

- Put `prjquota` into the options of root in `/etc/fstab`

Enjoy!