# Unable to create Local Volume

Tags: lvm

I am following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) link. I missed the "During the install of Ubuntu for the partitioning method choose guided - use the entire disk and setup LVM...". And reached upto lvcreate command(Manually installing an HVM Guest VM) which gives the error, "Volume group "vgubuntu" has insufficient free space (6 extents): 1024 required."*(The OS is Ubuntu, I had already tried in the [Ubuntu StackExchange site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337619/unable-to-create-local-volume-for-installing-xen))*

Now is there a way(without ending up on needing to format the entire hard disc or requiring a live cd or pendrive etc.) to assign enough memory[I have 1 SSD with around ~250GB, only ~60GB free space(no files etc.)]?

Certain Background info:

```
sudo vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name vgubuntu
System ID
Format lvm2
Metadata Areas 1
Metadata Sequence No 3
VG Access read/write
VG Status resizable
MAX LV 0
Cur LV 2
Open LV 2
Max PV 0
Cur PV 1
Act PV 1
VG Size 237.97 GiB
PE Size 4.00 MiB
Total PE 60921
Alloc PE / Size 60915 / <237.95 GiB
Free PE / Size 6 / 24.00 MiB

sudo vgs
VG #PV #LV #SN Attr VSize VFree
vgubuntu 1 2 0 wz--n- 237.97g 24.00m

sudo pvs
PV VG Fmt Attr PSize PFree
/dev/sda2 vgubuntu lvm2 a-- 237.97g 24.00m

sudo lvs
LV VG Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Meta% Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
root vgubuntu -wi-ao---- <237.00g
swap_1 vgubuntu -wi-ao---- 976.00m
```

I am using ext4.

Questions:

1. Isn't this the right thing to do:
   `lvreduce --resizefs -L 212G vgubuntu/root`[Tries to shrink the filesystem first(--resizefs is a lifesaver!) and if successful reduce the size of existing root to 212GB, so that "Alloc PE / Size 60915 / <237.95 GiB" becomes "Alloc PE / Size *(a New PE)* / <212 GiB*(approx.)*"]
   `lvcreate -L 8G -n ubuntu-hvm /dev/vgubuntu`[Creates a Logical Volume with 8GB for the VolumeGroup vgubuntu]
2. Is there ***any*** other way which I could do it without unmounting(probably not!)?

Comment: Have you tried `lvreduce` + `lvcreate`? Those commands look good. Your main question then seems to be whether you can do that without unmounting the logical volume. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, I was not sure if the procedure I learned from the web is correct. Plus I wanted also to check if there was an easy way without any external devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `lvreduce` command would be correct **if** it was possible to on-line shrink your filesystem.

Unfortunately ext4/ext3/ext2 filesystems can only be extended but not reduced on-line.

Tested on Debian, but even [the release notes of the most recent `e2fsprogs` source package](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/e2fsprogs-release.html#1.46.2) don't indicate this has changed at all.

```
# lvcreate -L 8g -n lvtest vgsys
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/vgsys/lvtest
# mount /dev/vgsys/lvtest /mnt
# lvreduce --resizefs -L 4G /dev/vgsys/lvtest
Do you want to unmount "/mnt" ? [Y|n] n
fsadm: Cannot proceed with mounted filesystem "/mnt".
  /sbin/fsadm failed: 1
  Filesystem resize failed.
```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227318/258991) describes a procedure that avoids rebooting, but it still requires transitioning to a `tmpfs`-based temporary root filesystem for shrinking the real root filesystem.

Comment: Looks like there are no easy way to do it!